# Cannot import PyQt5 modules

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pip, pyqt5

I installed PyQt5 as following:

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

Nevertheless, when I run the module, the output is an error telling me that QtWidgets cannot be imported as any other Qt module.
I then tried different syntaxes as:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
```

or

```
from PyQt5 import PyQt5.QtWidgets
```

None of those options are working.

Comment: The second form is incorrect, change `from PyQt5 import PyQt5.QtWidgets` to `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets`. What is your OS and what version of Python3 do you have?

Comment: What is the actual specific error you get? Include it in the question

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried that one as well but it is not working
I have Python 3.6 and running on OS 10.12

Comment: @MrJLP the error is :

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWidgets'

Comment: You need to understand what the error means. It can't find the python module. It's an issue with your path or a mismatch on two versions of Python

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
```

You can use it like that.It works for me.

Comment: Hi Emre! Can you explain your answer?

Comment: I just imported like above.Then compiler didnt give error.Maybe this error can be in past and should be fixed now.